# $ \frac {( - 1)^n}{n!}\int_1^2 (\ln x)^n\ dx $

Tags: integration

> $ \frac {( - 1)^n}{n!}\int_1^2 (\ln x)^n\ dx  $

Actually to prove this equal some series.
I tried substituting $x=e^t$ but since there it does not form any special function like gamma or beta i am unable to proceed.
Any other methods are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$
Try putting $x=e^{-t}$ and use the incomplete $\Gamma (x)$ function.

Comment: Where can i get complete information about this incomplete integrals.

Comment: Maybe wikipedia